# Attaching MDF without LDF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I only have an `.mdf` file of my database which is not attaching.

I am using the following command:

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'Test_Data', 
@physname = N'D:\Test_Data\Test_Data.mdf';
```

and I get the following error message:

> Msg 1813, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Could not open new database 'Test_Data'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>   Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
>   SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:24; actual 0:0). It occurred during a
>   read of page (1:24) in database ID 11 at offset 0x00000000030000 in
>   file 'D:\Test_Data\Test_Data.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL
>   Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is
>   a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be
>   corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check
>   (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more
>   information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Please help!

Comment: Have a look at this post - it discusses how to rebuild the log in emergency mode, but as it requires a restart of SQL server isn't something to do on your Prod Server (Nb - Jose Basilio's answer, not the accepted one) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773059/how-to-recover-database-from-mdf-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: @nonnb I've done this already but received error `Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.` when executing this statement `Update sysdatabases set status = 32768 where name = "BadDbName"`

Answer (score 4):

Your MDF is actually corrupt, based on that error message. This means you can't attach it.

You could create a database with the same name, substitute MDF (and rename LDF), and hope it comes online or at least suspect to start recovering it.

Otherwise, you'll need to find a 3rd party tool that understands MDF files to get data back.

Or just restore from your latest backup...?

Answer (score 4):

You could try this - if your MDF is intact (which according to your error message it doesn't seem to be.....):

```
USE master
GO 

CREATE DATABASE Test_Data
ON PRIMARY 
(FILENAME = N'D:\Test_Data\Test_Data.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

The `FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG` will attempt to create a new (empty) log file for your database.

Answer (score 1):

The DB was not closed/shut down correctly and it needs its LDF file to open/attach. Find one and do a graceful shutdown. After it you may try to attach single file DB from its MDF

Otherwise your way will be long and hard. Use [OrcaMDF](http://improve.dk/archive/2011/05/03/introducing-orcamdf.aspx) free library to access the data, or various commercial tools.

Comment: This is what the Problem is as my Question Title says. Is there any way I can recover my data from MDF?

Comment: Corrected answer

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try this. I got the answer from an [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/189be01f-23de-48b0-96cc-8f1292c13c54/).

- make a copy of your mdf file and change the extention (.mdf) to (.ldf)
- attach the mdf file using SSMS (note you have to locate the .ldf file)
- if you click ok ( error will occur) thats normal.
- select the ldf file and click remove. SQL server will automatically create a new ldf file for your attached mdf file.
- click OK now and your done..